# Arch Linux: Apache just isn't interpreting the index.php files

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd, php

I'm on Arch Linux, I installed the `apache`, `php`, `php-apache` and `mariadb` packages.

I have added the following line to the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

However it doesn't seem to make a difference.

It recognizes index.html files flawlessly, it renders them correctly as well. However if it's a index.php file then it just reads it as-is. What I get on the browser is the text contents of the file, as if it was a text editor but without the text editing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forget to add handler for php script.

Have you [tried this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP) yet?

Comment: Thanks for that link. Somehow I seem to have missed the PHP section, after dozens of times of reading this guide. :P